# Is there a more compact way to use the IF loop functioning in a batch file?

Tags: batch, batch-file

The classical way is

```
if "%name%"=="john" goto ok
if "%name%"=="eric" goto ok
if "%name%"=="mary" goto ok
```

But can this be done in more compact way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
for %%f in (john eric mary) do if "%name%"=="%%f" goto ok
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no OR operator, so what you're doing there is generally the most "compact" way in an MS batch.

More info, including some alternative ideas (no more 'compact' though):

- [IF… OR IF… in a windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438511/if-or-if-in-a-windows-batch-file)
- [Using an OR in an IF statement WinXP Batch Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273433/using-an-or-in-an-if-statement-winxp-batch-script)